# How to backup zimbra mail server?

Tags: linux, zimbra

I am newbie in linux. I am recently trying to backup zimbra mail server for making a backup server by `rsync` tool. I am copying `/opt/zimbra` folder but it is always giving errors. I am using `rsync -avzHS ssh /opt/zimbra root@16.3.8.98:/opt/zimbra`. I need to know which folders and which not I need to backup for making a backup server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zimbra` instruments to do the backup as it is described [here](http://docs.zimbra.com/docs/ne/4.0.5/administration_guide/10_Backup_Restore.15.1.html):

full backup:

```
zmbackup -f -s server1.domain.com -a all -t /path/to/backup
```

incremental backup:

```
zmbackup -i -s server1.domain.com -a all -t /path/to/backup
```

The usual reason you can't do it with `rsync` is because some files are open from `zimbra` processes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But zmbackup is not included in the latest zimbra collaboration suite software. Is there any other way I can do backup?

Comment: @HasanZafrul, in such case you should buy Zimbra Collaboration Backup & Restore Tool or Zimbra Backup Plus